Get intent error in Watson Assistant API call
I have a chatbot I made in Watson Assistant that I want to use the API for to query intents.
It yields this error:
    at RequestWrapper.formatError (C:\Bill\CC\js\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:313:21)
    at C:\Bill\CC\js\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:299:45
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  statusText: 'Not Found',
  status: 404,

In NodeJS, here is my code:
    const AssistantV1 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v1');
    const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
    
    const assistant = new AssistantV1({
        authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey:'xxx' }),
        serviceUrl: 'https://api.us-east.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/23c2475b-29a3-4249-9710-50f44a271958',
        version: "2020-04-01" 
        });
        
    const params = { workspaceId: 'dfe73de9-ced1-4cc0-909e-690cc8696c4d', intent: 'hello' };

    assistant.getIntent(params)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.result, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });


The APIkey is good and I got the workspaceID to use from the Assistant Id field as well as the service URL from the Assistant IDs and API details menu in the IBM app.
